# How to configure several external « application.properties » in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

As explained in [overriding-properties-at-runtime](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#overriding-properties-at-runtime), I can defined an external conf file in `./config/application.properties`

What I would like to achieve is to get several external application.properties.
For instance one in `./conf1/application.properties` and another one in `./conf2/application.properties`

So that I can separate, for instance, my standard and non secured properties from my secured properties (like password or secrets).

It is useful to apply different permission on those file, or if you are in k8s you can have a dedicated secret injected as file (and not as env var).

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Luisao, this is not currently supported but will be part of Quarkus 1.11 that we will release in January.

I will release a 1.11 Beta1 on Monday and it will contain this change so you will be able to experiment with it very soon.

Comment: I just tested with 1.11-beta2
and it works correctly using the followings properties:

smallrye.config.locations=./config/security.properties

But when I tried to use it with the native compilation inside docker then it fails ( my props inside ./config/security.properties are not found)

any idea ?